# Load UITableView with NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` where each dictionary has the same keys.  I want a section for each dictionary in the array.

For example, if the array has 4 dictionaries, then the table will have 4 sections.  Then each cell in each section will correspond with that value in the dictionary.

Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, I have an NSArray with 3 Dictionaries where each dictionary has 3 keys, name, gender, and date.

This means that the table should have 3 sections, where each section title is the date key for its dictionary.  Then there are 2 cells for that section corresponding to the name and gender values.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html  See: numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Ya I'm familar with those methods, but I'm not sure how to get the date key from the dictionary correctly setup in the `titleForHeaderInSection` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ya I'm familar with those methods, but I'm not sure how to get the
>   date key from the dictionary correctly setup in the
>   titleForHeaderInSection method.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return (NSString *)[myArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"date"];
}
```

> This worked flawlessly. But how can I edit the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath in a similar manner?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    /* Create myCell UITableViewCell */

    NSString *value = @"Unknown";
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        value = (NSString *)[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:"name"]; 
    }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        value = (NSString *)[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"gender"]; 
    }

    myCell.textPropertyOrWhatever = value;
    return myCell;
}
```

Are you even trying this at all? :P

Comment: This worked flawlessly.  But how can I edit the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in a similar manner?